# Render a controller template from a custom module in a theme page

Tags: theming, page-controller

I have created a custom module whose routes are defined as follows.

```
bigdeal_infos.infos_controller_infosScreen:
  path: '/bigdeal_infos/infos'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\bigdeal_infos\Controller\InfosController::infosScreen'
    _title: 'Infos Controller'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

When I go to *site.com/bigdeal_infos/infos*, the custom/bigdeal_infos/templates/example.html.twig template shows up with dynamic content passed from `infosScreen()` (a controller method).

I want to show this template file in a content page, *Home*, which uses *page--home.html.twig* as template file, in my theme.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: I think the only why to use this template inside content type page is to create a block programmatically and in the build method do the logic you did in `infosScreen` and than render the block inside your block inside page--home.html.twig

Comment: Okay I will try that. I hoped for an easier way out of this but thanks

Comment: Or if you know what to pass to twig you can make use of twig include https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/include.html something like `{% include '@bigdeal_infos/example.html.twig' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}`

Comment: That wont execute the controller, will only include the template. If you want re-use the logic on the controller best is to use a block as suggested earlier.

Comment: Yes it won't execute the controller he can pass the variables to page--home.html.twig using preprocess, and than include the template, but still the best way is to use Block